# Организация построчного чтения\записи файла

Tags: java, файлы

Ребят помогите пожалуйста.
Никак не могу разобраться в записью и чтением файлов, так как в книжках все это очень бегло описано. Проблема у меня в том что если я запишу в текстовый документ числа от 1 до 10 в столбик, то при открытии или при сохранении файла моей программой они все выводятся в строку(записываются тоже в строку - блокнотом проверял). **Как сделать так чтобы переход на новую строку сохранялся??**

Код:

```
    File q;

class SaveFile implements ActionListener{
    FileWriter fw;

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        try {
            fw=new FileWriter(q);
            fw.append(lists.get(tp.getSelectedIndex()).getText());
            fw.flush();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {}
    }
}

class OpenFile implements ActionListener{

    JFileChooser of;
    int ret;

    String line;

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        try {
            of = new JFileChooser();
            ret = of.showDialog(null, "Открыть файл");
            if (ret == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                q=of.getSelectedFile();
                JTextArea text = new JTextArea();
                JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(text);
                scroll.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
                scroll.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
                tp.add(q.getName(), scroll);
                lists.add(text);
                i++;
                BufferedReader reader= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(q), "utf-8"));
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) lists.get(tp.getTabCount()-1).append(line);
            }
        }
        catch (IOException ex) {}
    }
}
```

Comment: Просто добавьте символ перевода строки при записи строк в файл.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как писали [@a_gura](/users/1439/a_gura) и [@Максим147](/users/20522/%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC147) (без примера кода), вам всего лишь надо добавить символ перехода на новую строку. Если не понятно, то делается это вот так:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        try {
            fw=new FileWriter(q);
            fw.append(lists.get(tp.getSelectedIndex()).getText());
            fw.append("\n"); //переходим на новую строку
            fw.flush();
            fw.close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.toString()); //чтобы хоть что-то знать о возможной ошибке
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Символ перевода строки добавьте!

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Write {
public void createFile(){
    try(FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("filename.txt")) {
        fw.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}

public void writeInfoFile(){
    try(PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter("filename.txt")) {
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
            pw.println(i);
            pw.append("\n");
        }
        pw.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}

public void readFile(){
    String line = null;
    try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("filename.txt"))) {
        while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

    } catch (IOException e) {

    }
}
```

}